# Change style of PGFplots 3d box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When making a 3d axis plot by means of PGFplots, one can for instance change the style of the grid with

```
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
```

. But when using

```
3d box=background|complete|complete*
```

in the axis options, how do I change the style of the 3d box? More specifically, I want to make the lines of the 3d box gray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `axis line style` for that

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10,}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
enlargelimits=false,
3d box=complete,
grid,
grid style={dashed,gray!40},
axis line style={gray!40}  %% <--------------------
]
\addplot3[surf]
{x^2-y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]